# Missing /proc/version_signature file

Tags: kernel, system76

I have a System76 Gazelle laptop running Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to setup Ubuntu Pro, but it always shows the error, `An error occurred when checking for Livepatch updates`. While troubleshooting this I noticed that the `pro` command was giving me the error `WARNING:root:failed to process /proc/version_signature.`

```sh
➜  ~ sudo pro status
WARNING:root:failed to process /proc/version_signature.
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: ___@___.___
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

Sure enough, this file is missing.

```sh
➜  ~ cat /proc/version_signature
cat: /proc/version_signature: No such file or directory
```

I haven't done any real extreme customization on this machine, like trying to use a custom kernel, so I'm not sure why this file would be missing. Any thoughts on how I can recover this file?

Edit:

`uname -r` shows that I was running kernel 6.0.6. I switched to 5.15.0 in the grub menu, and now `/proc/version_signature` is available.

```sh
➜  ~ cat /proc/version_signature 
Ubuntu 5.15.0-56.62-generic 5.15.64
```

I'm not certain why the 6.0 kernel is installed. An identical laptop has kernel 5.15. Attempts to uninstall the 6.0.x kernel wants to uninstall important packages.

```sh
➜  ~ sudo apt remove linux-image-6.0.6-76060006-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd-ppt-bin at dfu-programmer firmware-manager firmware-manager-notify firmware-manager-shared gnome-shell-extension-system76-power hidpi-daemon linux-headers-6.0.2-76060002
  linux-headers-6.0.2-76060002-generic linux-image-6.0.2-76060002-generic linux-modules-6.0.2-76060002-generic python3-evdev python3-pydbus system76-acpi-dkms system76-dkms system76-firmware-daemon
  system76-io-dkms system76-oled system76-power system76-wallpapers xbacklight
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-generic linux-image-6.0.6-76060006-generic linux-image-generic linux-system76 system76-driver system76-driver-nvidia
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 12.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: `/proc` is a pseudo-filesystem that exposes kernel parameters so AFAIK `/proc/version_signature` isn't an actual file that you could "recover" - what is the output of command `uname -rvs`?

Comment: Please provide the exact command which produced that error. Just `pro` is not helpful here. `pro` gives `usage: pro <command> [flags]
Try 'pro --help' for more information.`.

Comment: @steeldriver
```
➜  ~ uname -rvs
Linux 6.0.6-76060006-generic #202210290932~1669062050~22.04~d94609a~dev-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DY
```

Comment: @mook765, I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: @DavidBaucum so I guess system76 uses a non-Ubuntu kernel that doesn't set `CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE` ?