# Ubuntu 22.04 missing /proc/version_signature

Tags: kernel, 22.04, directory, versions, proc

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude E7440

sudo pro status

```
WARNING:root:failed to process /proc/version_signature.
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

Enable services with: pro enable <service>
[...]
```

uname -r

5.18.0-051800-generic

File /proc/version_signature is missing. File /proc/version exists.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Related question with discussion in comments: [Missing /proc/version_signature file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445776/missing-proc-version-signature-file). What is the output of `uname -v`?

Comment: uname -v gives: 
#202205222030 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun May 22 20:33:46 UTC 2022

Comment: So I guess it's a non-Ubuntu kernel, that doesn't set the `CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE` parameter?

Comment: Thank you steeldriver for your comments. I cannot answer to your question. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu site. I guessed the Kernel is Ubuntu!